# How to collect/reduce with respect to multiple variables?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have this code:

```
a == b + c + d - e
```

Is it possible to collect or reduce this expression into this:

```
c + d == a + e - b
```

where I focus on the left side of the equation.

I am only aware of ways to reduce an expression with respect to one single variable, but here I would like to reduce it with respect to `(c + d)`.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Are you only interested in this simple linear case? Perhaps you should give a more involved example, otherwise many answers will only deal with the trivial case... I don't believe there's a solution for reducing *anything* to $G(c,d) = H(a,b,e)$ starting from $F(a,b,c,d,e)=0$, but if these functions are polynomials then maybe yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
c + d + # & /@ (Subtract @@ (a == b + c + d - e) == 0) // Reverse

a == b + c + d - e /. a == c + d + x_ -> c + d == a - x

With[{t = c + d},
 Reduce[a == b + c + d - e /. t -> x, x] /. x -> t]    

With[{t = c + d},
  Reduce[Eliminate[a == b + c + d - e && t == x, {c, d}], x] /. x -> t]

(*c + d == a - b + e*)
(*c + d == a - b + e*)
(*c + d == a - b + e*)
(*c + d == a - b + e*)
```

---

```
Subtract @@ (a - d == b + c - e) == 0 /.  x_ - (c + d) == 0 -> c + d == x
With[{t = c + d}, 
 Reduce[-Subtract @@ (a - d == b + c - e) == 0 /. t -> x, x] /.  x -> t]
```

Comment: But the first two solutions won't work if the equation is something like `a - d == b + c - e`.

Comment: @xzczd, Updated.

Comment: +1 for the first one, which can avoid possible duplication of the name of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `Reduce` and `ReplaceAll` may help:

```
Reduce[a == b + c + d - e /. c -> aa - d, aa] /. aa -> c + d
(* c + d == a - b + e *)
```

---

There's a defection in the solution above: it won't work correctly if the original equation contains the variable `aa`, of course in most cases we can avoid the duplication of name manually without much effort, but here I'd like to add a safer one:

```
Reduce[a == b + c + d - e /. c -> # - d, #] /. # -> c + d &@Unique["a"]
(* c + d == a - b + e *)
```

`Unique` is used to create a symbol that has never been used. This solution will work even if `a` has got an value:

```
a = 1;
Reduce[a == b + c + d - e /. c -> # - d, #] /. # -> c + d &@Unique["a"]
(* c + d == 1 - b + e *)
```

---

Let's make it into a funtion:

```
newReduce[x_Equal, y_] := Reduce[x /. Solve[y == #, Cases[y, _Symbol, {-1}, 1]], #]
                          /. # -> y &@Unique["a"]
```

The first argument of `newReduce` is the equation, and the second one is the "multiple variables", for example:

```
Clear[a]
newReduce[a == b + c + d - e, c + d]
(* c + d == a - b + e *)

a = 2;
newReduce[x + r y + z == d a + 2 u - op/3, x + y + z]
(* x + y + z == 1/3 (6 d - op + 6 u + 3 y - 3 r y) *)

newReduce[x + r /y + z == d /a + 2 u - op/3, x y + y z]
(* x y + y z == 1/6 (-6 r + 3 d y - 2 op y + 12 u y) && y != 0 *)

newReduce[x + r /y + z == d a + 2 u - op/3, x y z]
(* x y z == -(1/3) z (3 r - 6 d y + op y - 6 u y + 3 y z) && y z != 0 *)
```

As you see, now it works not only for the "multiple variables" with the head `Plus`.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do with Map, rather than with Reduce. Like this:

```
eq = a == b + c + d - e;
 Map[Subtract[#, b - e] &, eq]
```

or like this:

```
Map[Plus[#, -b + e] &, eq]
```

In both cases the result is the desired one:

a - b + e == c + d